# Perform operations on different rows on a multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given I have the following MultiIndex Dataframe

```
                     date_a        date_b
index_a   index_b               
1          Foo     1/2/2018     1/1/2018
           Bar     1/3/2018     12/20/2017  
2          Foo     2/4/2018     3/6/2018
           Bar     2/2/2017     1/2/2017
```

How do I generate a series that gets the difference of date_a from Foo and date_b from Bar indexed by index_a

```
index_a   difference_of_a_and_b     
1          1:00:00  
2          2:00:00
```

I have found a way to do it by each index:

```
df.loc[1,'Foo']['date_a'] - df.loc[1,'Bar']['date_b']
```

Now, how do I it to all index_a

Comment: How do you want the result to look? The output will only have two rows.

Comment: a series of data indexed by index_a so something like:

    index_a   new_column 
    1          1:00:00 
    2         2:00:00

Comment: I can't understand that without any formatting inside the comments. Please edit your question.

Comment: I have found a way to do it by each index:

df.loc[1,'Foo']['date_a'] - df.loc[1.'Bar']['date_b']

Now, how do I it to all index_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.xs` to slice levels and subtract:

```
(pd.to_datetime(df.xs('Foo', level=1)['date_a']) 
     - pd.to_datetime(df.xs('Bar', level=1)['date_b']))

index_a
1    13 days
2   398 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, Thanks!